# Read from 2 collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections A and B.

Collection A records looks as follow:

```
{
  "_id" : int,
  "my_id" : int,
  "date" : date,
  "name" : string 
}
```

Collection B records looks as follow:

```
{
  "_id": int
  "status":string
}
```

For a specific id there can be unlimited records on collection A and maximum 1 record in collection B. The common field between the 2 collections is "my_id" from collection A and "_id" from collection B.

There are few cases:

1. Id have records in both collections - here I need a response as follow:

```
{
  "_id" : int,
  "status" : string,
  "orders" :
    [
      {
        "_id" : int,
        "my_id" : int,
        "date" : date,
        "name" : string      
      },
      {
        "_id" : int,
        "my_id" : int,
        "date" : date,
        "name" : string
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

2. Id doesn't have any record in collection A and have a record in collection B - here I need a response as follow:

```
{
  "_id" : int,
  "status" : string
}
```

3. Id have records in collection A but doesn't have record in collection B - here I need a response as follow:

```
{
  "_id" : int,
  "orders" :
    [
      {
        "_id" : int,
        "my_id" : int,
        "date" : date,
        "name" : string      
      },
      {
        "_id" : int,
        "my_id" : int,
        "date" : date,
        "name" : string
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

If there is a way by only one call I will appreciate some help.
I've tried aggregate pipeline but I didn't succeed in supporting all 3 cases.

Here is one of my tries but the third case isn't supported:

```
db.getCollection("collectionB").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
          "_id": givenId
        }
    },
    {
         $lookup: {
             "from":"collectionA",
             "localField": "_id",
             "foreignField": "my_id",
             "as": "orders"
         }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "status": 1,
            "orders": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$orders", []]
                    },
                    "then": "$$REMOVE",
                    "else": "$orders"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Can you post your current attempt and the error(s) you are facing now?

Comment: Yes, I've added it to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can start aggregation from collection B to handle case 1 and 2 first. Then, `$unionWith` collection A to `$group` them into case 3.

```js
db.colB.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: {
        $in: [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "colA",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "my_id",
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "orders": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              [],
              "$orders"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$$REMOVE",
          "else": "$orders"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "colA",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            my_id: {
              $in: [
                1,
                2,
                3
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "colB",
            "localField": "my_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "orders"
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "orders": []
          }
        },
        {
          "$unset": "orders"
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "orders": {
              "$push": "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sB9EuCVYllg)

Comment: Thank you! there is one false assumption in your response though.
In collection A the fields "_id" and "my_id" aren't necessarily the same.
I guess the second $match should be with "my_id"

Comment: @DBnoob updated the answer. Can you please provide exact sample json documents and expected results instead of just the schema next time?